# ESP8266 with HC05 : expecting to receive more bytes then the 63 received

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial, battery, hc-05

I'm trying to read a Ant BMS 32H with a ESP8266 and a HC05 module.
BMS is sending 146 bytes when asking for these by sending DB DB 0 0 0 0 (HEX)
I did test with my android phone and the app 'Serial Bluetooth Terminal' and I receive/see the 146 bytes.
When doing this with the ESP8266/HC05 I only receive 63 bytes.
I saw already that I shouldn't use delays before reading the serial buffer, as this could cause buffer overflows.

I have no clue on what the reason could be ... hope someone has some more knowledge then I do ...
Please see my code I use ( I didn't post the Process_Data() routine as this one is called afterwards )
Initial I tried without the cosmetic visualization ( extra lines of code taking cpu cycle to execute) and it give the same result

The result I receive :

```
---------------------------------------------------
Sending request (6 bytes) : DB DB 0 0 0 0  Answer :
00:AA 01:55 02:AA 03:FF 04:02 05:7B 06:08 07:43 08:08 09:43 
10:08 11:47 12:08 13:41 14:08 15:3B 16:08 17:45 18:08 19:41 
20:08 21:46 22:08 23:43 24:08 25:41 26:08 27:43 28:08 29:46 
30:08 31:44 32:08 33:41 34:08 35:49 36:08 37:41 38:08 39:43 
40:08 41:42 42:08 43:3F 44:08 45:3F 46:08 47:46 48:08 49:44 
50:08 51:4F 52:08 53:38 54:08 55:3E 56:08 57:47 58:08 59:47 
60:08 61:45 62:08 
Bytes received : 63
```

My .ino :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>;
SoftwareSerial EEBlue(12, 13); // RX | TX // AT command mode
// byte message[] = {0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5A, 0xDB, 0xDB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x0A };
byte message[] = {0xDB, 0xDB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
byte bms[147]; // 82 + 65 = 147 bytes
int i;
int x;
int highbyte, lowbyte;
uint16_t a16bitvar;
unsigned int BattSOCG;
float BattPowerG;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
  EEBlue.begin(38400);  //38400 Baud for AT commands , set by command : AT+UART=38400,1,0 or AT+UART=9600,1,0
  delay(500);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Serial and Bluetooth started.");
  Serial.println(); Serial.println("");
}
 
void loop()
{
  AskBMSData();
  GetBMSData();
  Process_Data();
  delay(3000);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------
void AskBMSData()
{
  Serial.print("Sending request ("); Serial.print(sizeof(message)); Serial.print(" bytes) : ");
  for (i=0; i<sizeof(message); i++)
  {
    Serial.print(message[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  
  EEBlue.write(message, sizeof(message));
}

void GetBMSData()
{
  Serial.println(" Answer :");
  // Feed any received bluetooth data to Terminal.
  i=0;
  while (EEBlue.available()) {
    bms[i]= EEBlue.read();
    if(i<10) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(i); Serial.print(":");
    if(bms[i]<16) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(bms[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    x = (i+5)/10; x = 10*x-1; if(i==x) Serial.println();
    i++;
  }
  Serial.println(); Serial.print("Bytes received : ");Serial.println(i);Serial.println();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------
```

**Code changed based on Chrisl's response to :**

```
void GetBMSData()
{
  Serial.println(" Answer :");
  // Feed any received bluetooth data to Terminal.
  i=0;
  if (EEBlue.available()) {
      while (i<146) {
        bms[i]= EEBlue.read();
        i++;
        }
  }

  for (z=0; z<i; z++) {
    if(z<10) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(z); Serial.print(":");
    if(bms[z]<16) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(bms[z], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    x = (z+5)/10; x = 10*x-1; if(z==x) Serial.println();
  }
  Serial.println(); Serial.print("Bytes received : ");Serial.println(i);Serial.println();
}
```

with result :

```
---------------------------------------------------
Sending request (6 bytes) : DB DB 0 0 0 0  Answer :
00:AA 01:55 02:AA 03:FF 04:02 05:71 06:08 07:23 08:08 09:23 
10:08 11:26 12:08 13:21 14:08 15:1B 16:08 17:25 18:08 19:1E 
20:08 21:27 22:08 23:24 24:08 25:1E 26:08 27:23 28:08 29:27 
30:08 31:25 32:08 33:1F 34:08 35:28 36:08 37:21 38:08 39:22 
40:08 41:22 42:08 43:1C 44:08 45:23 46:08 47:28 48:08 49:26 
50:08 51:31 52:08 53:17 54:08 55:1E 56:08 57:28 58:08 59:29 
60:08 61:25 62:08 63:FF 64:FF 65:FF 66:FF 67:FF 68:FF 69:FF 
70:FF 71:FF 72:FF 73:FF 74:FF 75:FF 76:FF 77:FF 78:FF 79:FF 
80:FF 81:FF 82:FF 83:FF 84:FF 85:FF 86:FF 87:FF 88:FF 89:FF 
90:FF 91:FF 92:FF 93:FF 94:FF 95:FF 96:FF 97:FF 98:FF 99:FF 
100:FF 101:FF 102:FF 103:FF 104:FF 105:FF 106:FF 107:FF 108:FF 109:FF 
110:FF 111:FF 112:FF 113:FF 114:FF 115:FF 116:FF 117:FF 118:FF 119:FF 
120:FF 121:FF 122:FF 123:FF 124:FF 125:FF 126:FF 127:FF 128:FF 129:FF 
130:FF 131:FF 132:FF 133:FF 134:FF 135:FF 136:FF 137:FF 138:FF 139:FF 
140:FF 141:FF 142:FF 143:FF 144:FF 145:FF 
Bytes received : 146
```

Comment: you are printing six characters for every one received ... you could use hexadecimal addressing to reduce the number of lines printed ... first line would be `00 : AA 55 AA FF 02 71 08 23 08 23 08 26 08 21 08 1B` ... second line `10 : 08 25 08 1E 08 27 08 24 08 1E 08 23 08 27 08 25`

Comment: Indeed a nice way to visualize the output, but as I like to pick out certain byte visually, I like to be able to see at first view with one I need. But way of visualizing doesn't change/solve the problem, as now I do the visualization afterwards ones I have all bytes in variables.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 things, that might give you problems. First the one with a higher chance of being the important point:

You use

```
while (EEBlue.available())
```

in your `GetBMSData()` function. With serial (and especially over a packeted protocol like bluetooth) the sender might introduce pauses in the transmission of the data (for example when it needs to wait for more data, doing other tasks than sending or when a bluetooth packet ends and a new one must be send). You cannot control if and when these pauses happen. They might be big enough so that your `while()` loop can clear the internal buffer of the `SoftwareSerial` library without already having received the full message.

With serial you cannot think of a message as one block of data, which arrives together at the same time. You need to account for it to take its time. For example you could loop inside that function, until you have received the full message. That would fit to your current code structure. Something like this:

```
while(i<146){
  if(EEBlue.available()){
    bms[i]= EEBlue.read();
    i++;
  }
}
```

Note: If for whatever reason less than the expected number of bytes is send, this code will block forever - or until it received that many bytes.

Or - if you want to do it non-blocking (also rewriting the rest of the code), then you could just allocate a buffer big enough for the whole message and only place the bytes as they arrive inside that buffer. The rest (like sending the data out over `Serial` can then be done, when you have all the data bytes of the message. In this case you don't need a `while` loop, since the `loop()` function already handles the looping. You just test on very loop iteration if data is available and read it. After you read a byte you test for the message being complete. If yes, do the printing and processing.

---

The second problem is not that probable, but I still want to include that here. You are doing quite some printing inside the `while` loop, printing at least 6 bytes for every received byte. Serial can take some time and if it takes to long you can fill up your buffer in the background, effectively loosing data. I would suggest using the `while` loop to just `read()` the bytes and save them in your array. The printing can then be done after the full message was received. For the human reading the Serial printout it will not be different, but you can prevent losing data this way.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to implement "For example you could loop inside that function, until you have received the full message." I tried to change my code, see edit original post

Comment: I added a small code snippet to my answer. Hope that helps